# Getting started with ROR on top of an existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a web interface which is using a database for its contents. The database is pretty much arbitrarily designed without following any standard.

I want to write some APIs on top of this database. My front-end is going to consume these APIs.

I am using ActiveRecord as the ORM. The problem is that I am unable to define any associations or joins on my existing tables as both of these operations expect a column named `id` in the referenced table.

What's the way to go about it given that I don't want to temper my existing database schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define associations you can use additional options like :foreign_key and  :primary_key to specify details about such field names.

```
belongs_to :person, :primary_key => "name", :foreign_key => "person_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the past I tried to use ActiveRecord to work with legacy databases, and was successful, however, in doing so, I was definitely going against the flow. ActiveRecord didn't want to use fields and tables with different naming conventions, so it took a lot of work. Since then it's become a bit more civilized and is more lenient in its "not invented here" attitude. But, it's also not the only ORM in town, and I have become a big fan of Sequel for this sort of task.

You can use [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) as a substitute for ActiveRecord. It's a great ORM, that plays well with legacy databases. You can define what your `:id` fields should be, along with specifying all the real field and table names if they don't map to the expected format.

Take a look at the ["Cheat sheet"](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html) for an overview of how Sequel works, and ["Sequel for ActiveRecord Users"](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html) for how it can replace ActiveRecord for your use.

Use:

- "[Connecting to a database](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html)" for information about connecting to your database.
- "[Association Basics](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html)" and "[Advanced Model Associations](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/advanced_associations_rdoc.html)" for information about associating your models, and using different field and table names than the default mappings assume.

The [Sequel-talk group](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/advanced_associations_rdoc.html) is very active, and can point you in the right direction if you need help. And, the main author, Jeremy Evens, is an excellent example of a project lead -- he's always been helpful.

Comment: I second this suggestion, although DataMapper (http://datamapper.org/) might be something to look into if you don't like Sequel.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Sinatra instead of Rails. If all you want is just providing an API for a "ugly" database, don't start with activerecord.

Add your routes, and define SQL statements directly in your actions. Shouldn't be more costly than tinkering with activerecord's expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few options for you:

1. You rebuild your schema with ActiveRecord in mind and then write some scripts that import the old data into the new schema; (best solution IMO, although time consuming)
2. You don't use ActiveRecord and instead you access the database directly; (ugly)
3. You keep using ActiveRecord with the old data and use, as thorsten müller suggests, special arguments that tell Rails what columns to use as keys etc. (ugliest, will require quite a few hackarounds)

Picking one of these depends a lot on your requirements -- how fast it should be done, if the old data has to be kept (in which case you can't really go with 1.), how messed up the current schema is etc., but I think you should try to push towards option 1.